# Facing Issue in Updating data in Cloud Firestore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I am updating just 5-6 keys which are 2 levels nested in the perticular document. But Firestore update query takes almost 180ms time. Why is it too much slow? How can I optimize and take down to 10-15ms?

Comment: You could move closer to the server, or upgrade the routers and network quality in the network path between you and the server.  But you can't really just make a code change to improve the performance of a single API call.

Comment: my firestore db is in the nearest region only. I am thinking this is costlier operation. If through code if I can optimize then it would be much better